# Rightview on UITextField does not disappear on editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, editing

I have a `rightView` on `UITextField` with the mode `UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing`, so it should disappear when we are editing the textfield.

But now when I start editing the textfield programatically when you press the rightView (an edit button) the rightView does not disappear immediately. It only disappears when I start typing something.

So why does editing for a `UITextField` only start on typing and not on becoming first responder? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the < UITextFieldDelegate > to your interface.

Then set the delegate or your textfield to self (either in IB or) for example in viewDidLoad:

```
 self.theTextField.delegate = self;
```

Add this method to your .m :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    // Whatever is supposed to happen when you begin to edit the textfield happens now

}
```